# check if checkbox :check is not working, why, jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to check if the box is checked or not with *jquery*. It doesn't work but I don't get why.

If I refresh the page and keep the checkbox check, then it will echo alert.

```js
if($("#faith").is(':checked')){
    alert('hello');
}
if($("#diet").is(':checked')){
    alert('hello');
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="cureway" id="faith" value="faith" /><label for="faith">My faith</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="cureway" id="diet" value="diet"  /><label for="diet">My diet</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="cureway" id="exer" value="exer" /><label for="exer">My excercise</label>
```

Comment: where is those script kept.. is it in a change or some other event handler

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7ec0erpw/1/

Comment: Add in document ready function

Comment: It works fine..
https://jsfiddle.net/rrehan/sfo45mpb/

Comment: its working. what is the event that you are trying to execute this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".checker").change(function() {
        if ($("#faith").is(':checked')) {
            alert('hello');
        }
        if ($("#diet").is(':checked')) {
            alert('hello again');
        }
        if ($("#exer").is(':checked')) {
            alert('hello again too');
        }
    });
});
```

Html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cureway" id="faith" value="faith" class="checker" />
<label for="faith">My faith</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="cureway" id="diet" value="diet" class="checker" />
<label for="diet">My diet</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="cureway" id="exer" value="exer" class="checker" />
<label for="exer">My excercise</label>
```

Added a class to the checkbox.

https://jsfiddle.net/17m8wkwf/

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code

```
$(function(){
    $('input').on('click', function(){
    if($("#faith").is(':checked')){
    alert('hello');
    }
    if($("#diet").is(':checked')){
    alert('hello');
    }
       })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    if($("#faith").is(':checked')){
      alert('hello');
    }
    if($("#diet").is(':checked')){  
      alert('hello');
    }
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rrehan/sfo45mpb/1/) is the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/rrehan/sfo45mpb/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  if($("#faith").is(':checked')){
    alert('faith checked');
   }
   if($("#diet").is(':checked')){  
    alert('diet checked');
   }
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/gayanstar/sfo45mpb/2/)

Hope this helps